# How to limit the amount of times a while loop runs? C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int number1; 
    int number2;
    int answer; 
    srand(time(0));
    number1= rand()%10+1;
    number2= rand()%10+1;
    cout<< number1 <<" + " << number2 << endl; 

    cin>> answer; 

    if(number1 + number2 == answer) {
        cout << "correct"<< endl; 

    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect" << endl; 
        cout << "Answer:" << number1 + number2;
    }

    while(number1+number2==answer) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a program that asks the user a simple math question. In this final step, the user has to answer three questions correctly and then the loop will end.

If the user answers incorrectly, the loop will continue. My question is how can I do this? I'm confused on how to set up the loop in order for the program to work correctly.

Comment: Do you want to ask all three questions and then decide whether to proceed, or do you want a fast fail approach wherein a wrong answer will reprompt the user with the same question?

Comment: The user will answer one question. If correct, another question will follow. However, if wrong the user will be presented with a different question.

Comment: You never answered my question.  If the user answers incorrectly does he get prompted again with the _same_ question or does it move to the _next_ question?

Comment: It will move to the next question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a counter variable

ex: int count=0;

When the count variable reach 3 you execute a **break** statement inside the while loop

You have to increment the variable each time the user have a good answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you should have one `while` loop, containing three questions, and a counter for the number of correct answers.  If the user gets all three questions right, you can break out of the loop, otherwise you ask all three questions again.  So something like this might work for you:

```
int total = 0;

while (1) {
    cin >> answer;

    if (number1 + number2 == answer) {
        cout << "correct"<< endl;
        ++total;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect." << endl;
    }

    // include two more questions with if and else statements

    // check if all three answers correct
    if (total == 3) {
        cout << "You got every answer right!" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You got " << 3 - total << " questions wrong.";
        total = 0;
    }
}
```